# How to add string padding in textbox by importing textfile that has 2 values

Tags: c#, string, wpf, padding

This is my code for importing txt file to `TextBox` (it works). Now my question is how to add string padding like this:

dean harris...........dean.harris@outlook.com

Now it shows just:
dean harris, dean.harris@outlook.com.

I looked up a lot but didn't get any good result. I tried using the documentation but I couldn't figure it out. ==> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/padding

Thanks in advance!

```cs
private void BtnInlezen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(txtFile);
    try
    {
        using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(txtFile))
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            while (!file.EndOfStream)
            {
                builder.Append(file.ReadLine().Replace("\"", ""));
                builder.AppendLine();
            }
            
            TxtResultaat.Text = builder.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(txtFile))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "File not found");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("an unknown error has occurred");
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try: `file.ReadLine().Replace("\"", "").TrimEnd(',');`

Comment: So you want to replace the `", "` with `...........`?

Comment: @MarkusMeyer, thanks for your respond but that didn't change anything.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, kinda, or just with blanc spaces. it worked but then i didn't get the second value underneath each other, and that's the result what i'm looking for. I'm sorry if my English isn't that great! thanks for responding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you want to pad the string so here are two ways. The first center pads the string so they all have the same length and the second aligns the email addresses.

```
public static string CenterPad(string s, int maxLength, string delimeter, char replaceWith='.')
{
    int numDots = maxLength - s.Length + delimeter.Length;
    return s.Replace(delimeter, new string(replaceWith, numDots));
}
public static string AlignSecond(string s, int maxLength, string delimeter, char replaceWith='.')
{
    string [] parts = s.Split(new string[]{delimeter}, StringSplitOptions.None);
    return parts[0].PadRight(maxLength, replaceWith) + parts[1];
}
public static void Main()
{
    string [] tests = {"dean harris, dean.harris@outlook.com",
                       "john smith, john@example.com",
                       "sally washington, sallywashington@example.com"};
    foreach (var s in tests) {
        Console.WriteLine(CenterPad(s, 50, ", "));
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    foreach (var s in tests) {
        Console.WriteLine(AlignSecond(s, 25, ", "));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
dean harris................dean.harris@outlook.com
john smith........................john@example.com
sally washington.......sallywashington@example.com

dean harris..............dean.harris@outlook.com
john smith...............john@example.com
sally washington.........sallywashington@example.com
```

Comment: Hi! the AlignSecond is what i'm looking for! I tried to adjust it into my code but it only gives me the last row of the txt file. code in this link: http://pastie.org/p/2dvqfalnDtoMhXNrDLgyZN.
But thanks in advance this already helps a lot!

Comment: @SheldonTruyens You are overwriting `TxtResultaat.Text` each time. You can append each string instead: `TxtResultaat.Text += AlignSecond(line, 25, ",");`. You probably also want to append a newline after each string, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a string pad, you can use these methods https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/padding of class String , and manipulate the string before assing value to the property of object TxtResultaat.

Comment: hi! i already looked at the documentation of that. but I still can't figure it out how to apply it at one of the values from the textfile.. but thanks in advance!

Comment: A working code snippet would go a long way to improving this answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).